# Color Palette Swatches in UI

Tags: vertex-colors, vertex-paint

I'm using vertex paint to blend materials and i'd love to just have a red, green, blue swatches on the ui without having to go into the color picker every time
Is there an option or addon to bring swathces on the screen?